# Do I need multiple partitions for multiple flavors of Linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I am trying to install multiple kernels and DE/WM. I am aware that with one kernel, I can switch DE/WM fairly easily.

If I want to install more than one kernel in order to use features from both, do I need to create a new partition and install it there? Or can I, on one partition house all of my kernels and DE/WM, and just switch between them as I need?

Essentially I am trying to house more than one system on one computer, in a way that allows me to switch on the fly. Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'kernel' vs 'flavor of Linux'?

Comment: When I say kernel, I mean the actual kernel. I used "flavor" to describe any GNU/Linux distro, DE/Linux combo, or WM/Linux combo. I am not opposed to installing the kernel and wm/de separately.

Comment: Yeah but then your question title doesn't actually match the main post itself. The kernel is usually one of the least distinguishing parts of a Linux distro "flavor" (usually being a generic fits-all configuration), and most distros already allow multiple kernels to be installed on their own.

Comment: @grawity Right so, usually I'd be able to have multiple kernels, that makes sense. What I don't understand is where those kernels should go. Should these be installed alongside the main kernel in the same folder and partition? Or should these really just be installed on another partition? Sorry, I'm really just starting out with Linux. I should reiterate, I will likely be switching between the installed softwares often.

Comment: You're still describing the kernel as if it were the whole system – which it is not.

Comment: I am trying to use the work "kernel" to describe the software used to link the device components with applications. To be clear, when I say switching kernels, I am referring to the literal replacement of the kernel, and no part of the Desktop Environment or any GUI software. I do however plan on having multiple DE installed so I can switch between those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different **distribution** generally needs its own partition. A different **kernel** does not. Although the kernel is *in a way* the "core" of the OS, in reality it is very self-contained and constitutes only a very small part of the actual Linux distribution.

On a single Linux distribution, usually you already have the option to install several kernel versions. Each kernel is actually installed like any other software package, and multiple such packages can be installed at the same time without any conflicts.

For example, on the same Debian 10, you can install the `linux-image-rt-amd64` package (with the "real-time scheduling" features added) alongside the standard `linux-image-amd64`. Likewise on Arch Linux you have the `linux-lts` package ("long-term support" series) as well as the `linux` package (current 5.3.x series). The actual files that get installed have accordingly different names (e.g. vmlinuz-linux vs vmlinuz-linux-lts).

The result is that you can choose between the kernels in the boot menu, but the overall Linux distribution or "flavour" still remains exactly the same – you're still running the exact same system with the same installed software, same settings, etc. Hence a separate partition would not even make sense here.

---

Often the same applies to different flavors/environments of the same Linux distro. For example, Kubuntu 18.04 and Lubuntu 18.04 are fundamentally no different from the "main" Ubuntu 18.04 – they just come with different software preinstalled. It is easily possible to have multiple DEs or WMs installed on the same system, choosing the one you want at login time.

---

Multiple **distributions,** however, *would* conflict, as they would try to manage the exact same location in different ways. For example, `/usr/lib` in Ubuntu is arranged very differently from `/usr/lib` in CentOS, and cannot belong to both distributions at once – much like the same `C:\Windows` cannot be Win10 and Win7 at once.

So if you are planning to install multiple distros – such as Ubuntu and Debian, or Fedora and Arch – then you *do* need a separate partition for each. Each would then have its own set of kernels and its own installed software.

Note that if you create a separate partition for `/home`, it can be shared across all distributions easily, as its contents are considered to be outside the control of any distro's package manager.

(It is also technically possible to use a single partition for everything, by installing each distro to its own directory – having e.g. /arch/usr, /debian/usr, and so on – but it's usually not worth the trouble and most distros' installation tools will not actually allow this easily.)

Comment: Thank you for this very informative post. I have just one question. If I were to Install something like Manjaro, it sounds like I can switch between the different Manjaro kernels. But if I am not mistaken at this point, it would not be a good idea, or even be possible to try to install a gentoo kernel alongside the original majaro kernel. Right?

Comment: I think it would work fine, just wouldn't give you any advantages. (And it wouldn't turn the system into Gentoo.) As mentioned, the kernel is very self-contained, and the only really noticeable differences are: the version; the enabled features (and e.g. Gentoo tells you to choose those on your own anyway); and occassional distro-specific patches (mostly bugfixes or backports). So as long as it recognizes your hardware and has all the regular features expected from a desktop Linux kernel, it'll do the job regardless of what distro it comes from.